# Can I republish my derivative work using a new license?

Tags: copyright, derivative-work, share-alike

Some background: the System Reference Document 5.1 ("SRD5") is an original work owned by Wizards of the Coast ("WotC"). WotC currently authorizes derivative works of SRD5 using two distinct licensing options: a share-alike license called the Open Gaming License Version 1.0a ("OGL" linked [here](https://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/SRD-OGL_V5.1.pdf)) and the CC-BY-4.0.

I've created a derivative work based on the SRD5 (derivative in that it duplicates portions of the original). Initially, I published using the OGL, but I am now looking to republish a new version using CC.

Under normal circumstances, I know that the owner of an original work can release, expand, and re-release that work under any number of licenses. But I'm unsure how the terms of the OGL and the derivative nature of the work modify these rights. Chiefly, I'm concerned whether republishing would violate the share-alike clauses of the OGL, thus terminating the license, and whether that would require me to remove the OGL version from distribution.

So, can I republish my derivative work using a new license, even though the previous license was share-alike?